# Detect if Circle is within Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know that when zooming a Google Map, it is possible to mandate that a circle fit within the map via:

```
map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
```

Is it possible to simply detect if the circle is contained within the map? E.g.

**This would return *true*:**

[image]

**This would return *false*:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**possible solution:**

```
google.maps.Circle.prototype.inViewPort=function(){
  var map=this.getMap();
  if(!map){
    return null;
  }
  try{
  var mb=map.getBounds(),
      cb=this.getBounds(),
      ub=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      ub.union(mb);
      ub.union(cb);
      return(ub.equals(mb));
  }catch(e){return null;}
}
```

**usage:** simply call `circle.inViewPort()` .

It will return `true` when the circle is fully visible inside the map, otherwise `false`.

When the circle is not associated with a map or the map hasn't finished initializing(the projection isn't available yet, happens when you call it before the first `bounds_changed`-event fires) it will return `null`

**How it works:**

It creates a empty `LatLngBounds` and extends it with the bounds of the map and the bounds of the circle. When the circle is fully visible the bounds of this `LatLngBounds` must be equal to the bounds of the map.